# joomla1.5 extension virtue mart :sample data installation problem

Tags: joomla1.5, virtuemart

I get this error after clicking Go directly to shop or install sample data from the virtuemart component. The module is also installed

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\Hosting\7116670\html\administrator\components\com_virtuemart\Tar.php on line 1443

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Is this a live site? In my experience you are better off using the Joomla+Virtuemart package rather than trying an install on an existing Joomla site.